# Use a vue component inside a router component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I use a route-view inside my App.vue, in my routes I'm using the component Base, what I want is call a 'teste' component inside a 'Base' component.

I already read about nested-named-views in vue-router, but not resolved my problem.

Route.js

```
import Base from './components/base/Base.vue';

export const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        components: {
          default: Base
        }
      },
```

App.vue

```
<div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
```

Base.vue

```
<template>
  <teste></teste> //this component dosent render
</template>

<script>
import teste from './SideBar.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Base',
  components: {
      teste
  }
}
```

SideBar.vue

```
<template>
    <p>teste</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'teste'
}
```

Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import {routes} from './routes'


Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: How do you import your routes inside the `main.js` ?

Comment: I added to the question

Comment: 1. Wrapping text (some code) in a `<teste>` component in a tag like `<p>` or `<div>` should help.

Comment: changed on the question.

Comment: try to change name in SideBar.vue file to name: 'SideBar'

Comment: I tried and don't work.